# Is there a way to give dynamic names to scripts with YepNope.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yepnope

I'm currently working with [YepNope.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js) to load my css/javascript files.  I was wondering if there is any way to give the scripts a variable name during the initial process.  For instance:

```
yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep  : ['MyCSS', 'jQuery']
    nope : ['MyCSS2']
});

// Where 'MyCSS' = '/css/mycss.css' | 'jQuery' = '/scripts/jquery.min.js' 
// 'MyCSS2' = '/css/mycss2.css
```

I have a team of devs that would all be using the same set of scripts and want to make it as easy as possible to handle.  Having to track down the script paths may prove time consuming over simple name assignments.

I want to be able to define a list of variable names that have the values of the actual script assigned to them that YepNope.js will interpret without the developer having to add the variable assignments to their projects code:

```
{ 'MyCSS': '/css/mycss.css', 'jQuery', '/scripts/jquery.min.js' }
```

That way when the developer adds their script files to their project they don't have to track down all the paths for the specified files.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to ask. yep is an array of strings, nope is an array of strings. You don't need to specify it inline.

Comment: Nope, not asking anything about inline.  Redefined the question a little to hopefully make it easier to understand.  Basically want to be able to use the variable names in place of the file paths when initializing.

Comment: Partially, I added a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
var yeps = ['/css/mycss.css','/scripts/jquery.min.js'];
var nopes = ['/css/mycss2.css'];

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep  : yeps,
    nope : nopes
});
```

or

```
var myCSSpath= '/css/mycss.css',
    jQpath = '/scripts/jquery.min.js',
    myCSS2path = '/css/mycss2.css';

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep  : [myCSSpath, jQpath],
    nope : [myCSS2path]
});
```

EDIT: so you want to put the variable assignments to a different file?

make a yepnope.variables.js

```
<script src="path/yepnope.js"></script>
<script src="path/yepnope.variables.js"></script>

<script>
yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep  : [myCSSpath, jQpath],
    nope : [myCSS2path]
});
</script>
```

and inside the js file:

```
var myCSSpath= '/css/mycss.css',
    jQpath = '/scripts/jquery.min.js',
    myCSS2path = '/css/mycss2.css';
```

Comment: The second one is essentially what I need, but I need to be able to do it prior to loading YepNope.  I don't want the developer to have to place those definitions in their actual code.  Load it in with YepNope itself

Comment: Wow.... seems so obvious I can't believe I missed it.  Exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: I was a little startled that you asked for a method to give short names for long strings.